# Single spacing long entries in List of Figures and moving page number

Tags: table-of-contents, line-spacing

I'm assembling my master's thesis in latex and I'm currently having trouble with spacing in my List of Figures. Currently, if there is an entry that extends more than one line, it is double spaced and the page number is on the bottom line. My university requires subsequent lines in a single entry to be single spaced, individual entries double spaced, and page numbers to be on the first line of each entry.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/5764) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/5764) that illustrates your problem. This will give community members an idea of the packages you already use/cannot use and help diagnose the problem quicker.

Answer (score 1):

For single spacing long entries, one of the solutions previously offered in this forum works: 
[Single Spacing Long Subsection Header in Table of Contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23445/single-spacing-long-subsection-header-in-table-of-contents)
The solution `\caption[\protect\vspace{-0.5ex}{long caption text}]{long caption text}` works, it may be a roundabout since you have to do it for each figure that has a long caption text, but atleast fixes it.

Comment: This seems to work for two lines... how do you extend this to multiple lines?