# Single Spacing Long Chapter Header in Table of Contents, Long Figure Captions in List of Figures

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, captions

I am finishing up my dissertation and have a small issue. The dissertation format asks for single spacing the chapter heading in table of contents if it is too long and can't fit in one line. The same goes for list of figures and captions. I followed the post [Single Spacing Long Subsection Header in Table of Contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23445/single-spacing-long-subsection-header-in-table-of-contents), and modified my chapter headings from something like

```
\chapter{Implementation and modification of a three dimensional radiation stress formulation for surf zone and rip-current applications}
```

to

```
\chapter[\protect \vspace {-2ex}{Implementation and modification of a\\ three dimensional radiation stress formulation\\ for surf zone and rip-current applications]{Implementation and modification of a three dimensional radiation stress formulation for surf zone and rip-current applications}
```

This only partially works as I get an output in my table of contents with first two lines with single spacing but the third line with double spacing.

What modification needs to be done if I want all three lines in this case to have single spacing? Also in general what should be done if I need "n" lines where n>2?

My class file is officially hosted [here](http://gradschool.sc.edu/students/filedownload-public.asp?file_name=uscthesis.cls&location=D:%5Cgradschool.sc.edu%5Cstudents%5Cdocs%5CUSCLaTeX%5Cuscthesis.cls), but it has also been [uploaded to pastebin](http://pastebin.com/UNHUcX0p) (33K).

Let me know if you would need more information to answer my question.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Possibly helpful: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43899/changing-the-linespacing-of-headings-independently-from-the-rest-of-the-text

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possibility. Let's suppose you're using `\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}` in your preamble to get double line spacing throughout your thesis. Then what you can do is put the `\tableofcontents` command inside a `\begin{spacing}{1}...\end{spacing}` environment: the `1` locally reverts the spacing to single.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}

\begin{document}

\begin{spacing}{1}
\tableofcontents
\end{spacing}

\chapter{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 
elit. Etiam condimentum lacus vel lacus commodo auctor.
Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia
nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.}

Nam fermentum, nibh in vehicula pretium, ligula nibh laoreet turpis,
rhoncus dictum lectus libero id tellus.

Donec ultricies neque ut augue ultricies suscipit vitae nec leo. Sed 
porta congue elit auctor vestibulum. Ut id ornare lectus, in convallis 
urna. Nunc bibendum venenatis est, nec auctor nulla lacinia malesuada. 
Duis commodo elementum lacinia. Phasellus nibh lorem, cursus vitae 
mauris non, pretium dictum diam.

\chapter{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Etiam condimentum lacus vel lacus commodo auctor. Class 
aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per 
inceptos himenaeos.}

Nam fermentum, nibh in vehicula pretium, ligula nibh laoreet turpis, 
rhoncus dictum lectus libero id tellus.

Donec ultricies neque ut augue ultricies suscipit vitae nec leo. Sed 
porta congue elit auctor vestibulum. Ut id ornare lectus, in convallis 
urna. Nunc bibendum venenatis est, nec auctor nulla lacinia malesuada. 
Duis commodo elementum lacinia. Phasellus nibh lorem, cursus vitae 
mauris non, pretium dictum diam.

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Note that the OP uses a specific class - [`uscthesis`](http://gradschool.sc.edu/students/filedownload-public.asp?file_name=uscthesis.cls&location=D%3a%5Cgradschool.sc.edu%5Cstudents%5Cdocs%5CUSCLaTeX%5Cuscthesis.cls) - that is based on [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir). And, `memoir` has its own line-spacing techniques, perhaps not compatible/different from what is offered by [`setspace`](http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace).

Comment: With `memoir` it should be `Spacing` rather than `spacing`.